# I am not able to add an event listener to a flycontrols.js instance in three.js

Tags: three.js

I switched the controls in a script I was writing from trackball controls to the fly controls. I added an event handler to trackballcontrols without problem.

```
controls.addEventListener( 'change', function () {

    cameraChanged = true;

    signals.cameraChanged.dispatch( camera );
    render();

} );
```

However when I tried to add the event listener to the flycontrols instance I received the error:

```
Object [object Object] has no method 'addEventListener'
```

I assume that the flycontrols class doesn't have a mechanism to add event listeners. I was wondering how I would go about adding it.

Answer (score 1):

`FlyControls` doesn't have `EventDispatcher` implemented.